# BeautifulSoup replaces single quotes with double quotes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In BeautifulSoup4 for Python if I exectue the following commands:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<a href='http://somelink'>link</a>")
print soup
```

The output is:

```
<a href="http://somelink">link</a>
```

BeaurifulSoup replaces single quotes with double quotes and I don't want that. How can I cancel/overwrite that behaviour?

CLARIFICATION:

I use urllib2 to get the html of the following page: `http://www.download3000.com/` and then use BeautifulSoup4 to extract only a part of the html.

I have made a function that takes a document (not always html) and some samples of what it needs to catch and returns a regular expression. 
I feed the function with the follwoing samples:

```
samples = [
    '/showarticles-1-0-date.html',
    '/showarticles-2-0-date.html',
    '/showarticles-3-0-date.html'
]
```

Given the html code of the `http://www.download3000.com/` page and the samples above, my function returns the following regular expressions: `\w\w><li><a href="(.*?)">\w\w\w\w\w`

If I apply the regex to the html code of download3000, it won't find any match. That's because the links are surrounded by single quotes in the html, but when I use BeautifulSoup it replaces single quotes with double quotes and the regular expression generated only works on the html modified by BeaurifulSoup.

That's why I need to force BeautifulSoup not to replace single quotes with double quotes, so that the generated regular expression will be `\w\w><li><a href='(.*?)'>\w\w\w\w\w`, thus extracting what I need from the page.

I could use a dump solution like replacing all the single quotes in my regex with `["\']`, but then the regex would also catch some links that I don't want.

Comment: Why do you not want that? The *meaning* is the same. BeautifulSoup is a library for giving you access to the *contents* of a HTML document, those contents are preserved just fine.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I'm writing a regular expression generator. Atm it generates regular expressions fine but the reg ex contains double quotes instead of single quotes because of BeautifulSoup and the reg ex that's generated won't match on the original document.

Comment: You *really* should avoid using regular expressions here. And your regex generator cannot be adjusted to use `["']` instead?

Comment: @IonutHulub: Why not just do a simple string replace?

Comment: I can't just use a single sting replace because then it would also catch double quotes, which I don't (always) want to be catched. I don't want to sound rude but it would be great if you stop questioning my reasons and just provide an answer.

Comment: There is no solution to your question; we are asking questions as to what your doing because this feels like a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); we are trying to help you solve the *underlying* problem instead.

Comment: I added a clarification to the post. Hope the problem is more clear now.

Comment: I don't think this is an XY post. While the OP has a reason he didn't explain up front for wanting to change BeautifulSoup's behavior, he asked a perfectly valid question. I have a different reason: I want to preserve the original characters as much as possible for users who like single versus double quotes for whatever reason. It doesn't matter if you don't see a purpose for doing so, as indeed, the meaning *is* the same - there are users who do see the purpose.

Comment: My bet is that BeautifulSoup (long may it live) returns double quotes because when it parses the content it uses single quotes to return the rest of the string eg `' <elem att="Value">" '`. I'd be surprised if there was a viable way to do it without having to add in an extra regex step that only replaces double quotes when they are preceded by an `=` or followed by a `>`

Answer (score -1):

This works with BeautifulSoup 3.2.  I assume what is happening is that as the single quotes are converted to `&quot;` The parser then surrounds them with "
Then on output the pattern `"'` or `'"` occurs

```
>>> c="<a href='http://somelink'>"
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> d=re.sub("'","&quot;",c)
>>> e=BeautifulSoup(d)
>>> def qfix(x):  return re.sub("\'\"|\"'","'",x)
>>> qfix((str(e))
```

You might be able to use similar to "qfix" as a formatter in BeautifulSoup 4

Or it might not work at all :)

Comment: This does not work for me with 3.2.1, but it should be added that I am already dealing with unicode HTML, so maybe the difference lies purely in the use of `str(e)` instead of `unicode(e)`.